# Difference between "seeks to promote" and "promote"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the sentence "UN seeks to promote international peace" and "UN promotes international peace"?

I think that in the first sentence, it's stated more like an objective of UN. In the second sentence, it's more like what UN actually does.

Is my inference correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

> someone **seeks** to do something

means it is an *objective* or *aspiration*.

Whereas

> someone **does** something

describes what they *do*.

Answer (score 0):

In this context the **seeks** is similar to **try**.

So the sentences with words switched would be "UN **tries** to promote international peace" and "UN promotes international peace"